# Chrome treats my search field as username field

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, autofill

Google Chrome keeps prefilling my search field with my email address. When I search, Chrome also asks if username/password needs to be stored in Chrome password vault.

I've Googel and tried multiple suggestions:

- creating unique names for the input field
- set autocomplete property to a unique value,
- set autocomplete to autocomplete_off

But the problem persists.

The element in question:

```
<input class="searchBox" id="citysearch" type="search" name="hw_citysearch676557b2-ccf7-48c3-ab96-e62c721d089a" autocomplete="autocomplete_off_hack_xfr4!k" data-lpignore="true" placeholder="Plaats of postcode" data-ol-has-click-handler="">
```

It looks like this in my Chrome browser:
[image]

See it live [here](https://www.huurwoningen.net/) on the homepage.

Comment: Can't repro. Both Chrome and Edge Chromium behave as expected. No username (*or email*) autofill and it does not prompt to save anything. Maybe you should try clean cache entirely and check it again.

Answer (score 1):

Since that is not the case for me in Chrome, it is most likely your browser cache.

To clear AutoFill cache, follow [these steps](https://support.iclasspro.com/hc/en-us/articles/218569268-How-to-Disable-and-Clear-AutoFill-Info-in-your-Browser). In particular, on Chrome:

1. Click the Chrome menu icon. (Three dots at top right of screen.)
2. Click on History, then click on History again in the menu that appears.
3. Select Clear browsing data. (Alternatively, you can press CTRL+SHIFT+DEL on your keyboard to bypass steps 1-3.)
4. At the top, choose “the beginning of time” option to clear all saved data.
5. Make sure that the “Clear saved Autofill form data” option is checked.
6. Click Clear browsing data.

You can select what to clear and limit it to AutoFill. If you just want to test that it works for the other users, you can try using another browser or private window in Chrome.